# How can I get media from instagram API?

Tags: angularjs, api, instagram-api

I'm using the instagram API to get some images related to an specific hastag but when I call the API I get a message saying the API is deprecated.

I'm calling this endpoint

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Any idea on what call I need to make to return the list of images with the requested hastag?

Comment: I got error "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead". Do you have error that whole endpoint is deprecated?

Comment: Yes, that is what I get.

Answer (score 1):

So I figure out why this is happening. Because the application is still in sandbox mode I can only get hashtag from the accounts that have access. Once the application is approved it will be able to pull the data from the API.